# Yii2 Navbar items from array

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have trouble with array helper. I have 2 models Menu and Submenu, in Menu model have function where i collect all parent and submenus like this:

```
public function getSubmenus()
{
    $db = self::getDb();
    $result = $db->cache(function ($db) {
        return $this->hasMany(Submenu::className(), ['parent_id' => 'id'])->andOnCondition(['enabled' => 1]);
    },86400);
    return $result;
}

public static function getMainMenu(){
    $db = self::getDb();
    $result = $db->cache(function ($db) {
        return Menu::find()->where(['enabled' => 1])->with('submenus')->all();
    },86400);
    return $result;
}
```

In my main layout:

```
$key = 'main-menu';
$cache = Yii::$app->cache;
$menu = $cache->getOrSet($key, function () {
    return Menu::getMainMenu();
},86400);
```

Now i have all my items in $menu variable.
So, next i trying  use standart Navbar:

```
NavBar::begin([
    'brandLabel' => Html::img('@web/images/logo.svg', ['alt'=>Yii::$app->name]),
    'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light',
    ],
]);
$menuItems = [
    ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
    ['label' => 'About', 'url' => ['/site/about']],
    ['label' => 'Contact', 'url' => ['/site/contact']],
];
echo Nav::widget([
    'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
    'items' => $menuItems,
]);
NavBar::end();
```

How to generate $menuItems with ArrayHelper::map and my variable $menu?

Comment: you havent provided the `print_r()` of the `$menu` , and you need to format the result set from the model to the required format for the `Nav` `items` option. you need more than `ArrayHelper` only.

Comment: I agree with @MuhammadOmerAslam, provide the `map` of the db tables and examples of data from both tables, to be able to assist you.